# mx:datagrid - ctrl + Click

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'd like to intercept <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and click on datagrid line.
I know how to do test if user click on datagrid line but how to add <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> event?

Firs part works like this:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dgRDVt" fontWeight="normal" 
                 dataProvider="{acList}" 
                 width="100%" height="85%" change="dgRdvPat_changeHandler(event)">
        <mx:columns>
```

...

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a `MouseEvent.CLICK` handler to determine this.

`MouseEvent` has a couple of properties to know if the user is pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key while clicking. [ctrlKey](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#ctrlKey) detects if they are doing it on Windows or Linux.  [controlKey](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#controlKey) is cross platform (works on Mac too).

So you should check the value of the `controlKey` property of the `MouseEvent`. Add a mouse click handler to the grid:

```
<mx:DataGrid click="onDataGridClick(event)"/>
```

Then in the event handler:

```
private function onDataGridClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (event.controlKey)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```